# How to make ASP.NET Core app (service not IIS) reachable from network

Tags: asp.net-core, service

I got a ASP.NET Core application, which I configured to run as a service (so there is no IIS on target maschine). Also, I want to use HTTP.sys.
My configuration looks like this:

```
var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseContentRoot(pathToContentRoot)
            .UseHttpSys(options =>
            {
                // The following options are set to default values.
                options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.None;
                options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
                options.MaxConnections = null;
                options.MaxRequestBodySize = 30000000;
                options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://localhost:5050");
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .Build();

        if (isService)
        {
            host.RunAsService();
        }
        else
        {
            host.Run();
        }
```

Look at the line

```
options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://localhost:5050");
```

This is pretty much standard. But: if I publish this application and install the service on a PC in my network, I cant reach it.

The PC has an IP, for example 10.35.39.113, and I can ping it. But when I try to connect via a browser (from another PC in LAN), open up *http://10.35.39.113:5050/* it says error **400 "Bad Request"**.

I added rules to the firewall, I disabled the firewall, I run

> netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:5050/ user=Users

but it did not work. The error changed from **400 "Bad Request"** to error **503 "Service Unavailable"**.

I only got it working by changing the UrlPrefixes.Add line to:

```
options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://*:5050");
```

But there is a big warning in the HTTP.sys documentation. [Link to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys?view=aspnetcore-2.0)

> Warning
>
> Top-level wildcard bindings (http://*:80/ and http://+:80) should not
>   be used. Top-level wildcard bindings can open up your app to security
>   vulnerabilities. This applies to both strong and weak wildcards. Use
>   explicit host names rather than wildcards. Subdomain wildcard binding
>   (for example, *.mysub.com) doesn't have this security risk if you
>   control the entire parent domain (as opposed to *.com, which is
>   vulnerable). See rfc7230 section-5.4 for more information.

Now I ran out of ideas.

What do I have to do to make my service reachable from the network?

Answer (score 2):

If you bind to `http://localhost:5000` then the server is listening on that exact address and port. Unfortunately you cannot call anything on `localhost` from outside of the local machine.

In the documentation it states:

> The settings in UrlPrefixes override UseUrls/urls/ASPNETCORE_URLS
>   settings. Therefore, an advantage of UseUrls, urls, and the
>   ASPNETCORE_URLS environment variable is that it's easier to switch
>   between Kestrel and HTTP.sys.

So, if you want to deploy to a different server but don't know the URL at build time then you can setup an environment variable to supply the URL prefixes instead. On Windows you would set the following environment variable:

```
ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://<machine_name>:5050"
```

*change `<machine_name>` to the local machine name.

Also remove the `options.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://localhost:5050");` from your code.

When you start the service you should be able to reach the service from anywhere that can see the machine it is running on.

Comment: I tryed it.. but it gives me error 400 "Invalid Hostname". In both cases, when I try to open up http://localhost:5050/ on the local maschine, also when I try to connect via IP from LAN. You got another idea? :)

Comment: What did you use for ASPNETCORE_URLS?

Comment: The full computer name (windows 7).

Comment: Here you can see. (its a picture of environment variable - german) https://imgur.com/a/Mevulnf

Comment: I can't see the picture (access is blocked where I work). If you are using the computer name then that is how you have to access the url e.g. `http://mycomputer.name.com:5050`. Localhost and IP won't work because it's not listening on those URLs. If you want to listen on more than one URL then the add them to the `ASPNETCORE_URLS`, separating them with `;` e.g. `http://localhost:5050;http://mycomputer.name.com:5051`.